# ThreeJS - Remove White Corners from Points

Tags: javascript, three.js

**WHAT I'M DOING**

I'm rendering circular points with varying vertex colors using a fragment shader. I in essence want the points to act as more performant spheres that are antialiased when zoomed all the way in.

**PROBLEM**

It works in one direction (see left photo), but the other direction has white corners (see right photo). How do I get rid of the white corners?

[image: Direction I want it to look like] [image: What I don't want]

**WHAT I TRIED**

- If the points were all the same color, I could turn off depthTest and it would just work. However, the points must be varying colors. Turning off the depthTest with varying colors makes it look like a wormhole.
- I tried alphaTest to no avail. I did get alphaTest to work with textures instead of a custom fragment shader (png of a circle on transparent background), but it looked blurry when zoomed in sufficiently.
- I did notice that the colors of the corners was equivalent to whatever I passed into renderer.setClearColor.
- I've played around with blending options, but I'm not familiar enough with blending yet to understand what I'm doing.

**CODE**

```
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
geometry.setAttribute( 'color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  transparent: true,
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
  uniforms: {
      size: {value: 20},
      scale: {value: 10},
  },
  defines: {
    USE_MAP: "",
    USE_SIZEATTENUATION: ""
  },
  vertexShader: THREE.ShaderLib.points.vertexShader,
  fragmentShader: `
  in vec3 vColor;
  void main() {
      vec2 xy = gl_PointCoord.xy - vec2(0.5);
      float ll = length(xy);
      gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, step(ll, 0.5));
  }
  `
});
const points = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
scene.add( points );
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to put `if (ll > 0.5) discard;` after `float ll = length(xy);`, and remove `transparent: true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove those corners, you can discard the pixels, whose length of UV position is greater than 0.5:

```js
  in vec3 vColor;
  void main() {
      vec2 xy = gl_PointCoord.xy - vec2(0.5);
      float ll = length(xy);
      if (ll > 0.5) discard; // this line does the trick
      gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, step(ll, 0.5));
  }
```